# How to cover by mock test static method InetAddress.getLocalHost()?

Tags: java, testing, mocking, mockito, powermock

I would like to cover by mock test one standard Java method, not all its realisation but only throwing an exception.
It looks like:

```
public static InetAddress getLocalHost() throws UnknownHostException {...}
```

And I use it in my code in this method:

```
 @Override
 @SneakyThrows
 public String getLocalHostName() {
    return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
 }
```

I've to write the following tests:

```
@Test
void testGetLocalHostThrowsUnknownHostException() throws Exception {
    mockStatic(InetAddress.class);
    when(repository.getLocalHostName()).thenThrow(new Exception("exception message"));

    assertThrows(UnknownHostException.class, InetAddress::getLocalHost);
}
```

but always see an error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Checked exception is invalid for this method!
Invalid: java.lang.Exception: exception message
```

Any there any possibilities to check the exception by mock test?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when you use 'mockStatic()' you need to put it inside try-with-resources, then you cant throw an Exception here because the method is declared to throw only the `UnknownHostException`.
You need to throw `UnknownHostException`. Then when you do assertThrows you dont need to pass `InetAddress::getLocalHost` because you are testing repository method `getLocalHostName()` So test will look like

```
@Test
    void testGetLocalHostThrowsUnknownHostException() {
        try(MockedStatic<InetAddress> inetAddressMockedStatic = mockStatic(InetAddress.class)) {
            inetAddressMockedStatic.when(InetAddress::getLocalHost).thenThrow(UnknownHostException.class);
            assertThrows(UnknownHostException.class, () -> repository.getLocalHostName());
        }

    }
```

Comment: I've tried already test like this but I see an error:
'org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
The used MockMaker SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker does not support the creation of static mocks'

Comment: Did you add mockito-inline to gradle/maven? And try to add 
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) to your test class

Comment: Yes, I've added it. And I have JUnit 5, so I have in my test class '@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)'

Comment: if you have mockito-core than remove mockito-core from your dependencies (mockito-inline depends on mockito-core so it will be retrieved automatically). And i recommend to add @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) too

Comment: nope, it did not help me out too
but thanks anyway